# Twitter API complains about Basic Authentication, but I'm using OAuth

Tags: php, twitter

I am creating a web-application which is using the Twitter API. I use the EpiTwitter library and OAuth authentication, however from time to time, randomly I got this weird error:

> [{"code":53,"message":"Basic authentication is not supported"}]

First, I thought that I ran out of API requests but I still have 190+ generally. Could you help me?